# Toggle Click On Select Tag - React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I am working on a react app that is when a user clicks on a single text it will show a select tag with items on it.

I have two problems showing up here:

1. When I click on the text, the select tag will appear on **ALL** the list item instead of the item that was click.

For instance I have list:

```
--------------------------------
name          item
--------------------------------
George        text
Mikael        text
```

When I click on the text for george, both george and mikael will display the select tag. Which is not what I want to do. It must only show on the list item that was clicked.

2. After selecting an item from the select tag, it must retain that state and it will become the default value of the "text".

For instance:

```
--------------------------------
name          item
--------------------------------
George        text
Mikael        text
```

If I click on george text and then the select tag for george will appear. if I select the value: `item 1` it must retain that and make it the default value of the text so the output will be like this and then select tag will disappear again and then if it was click it will appear again and vice versa:

```
--------------------------------
name          item
--------------------------------
George        item 1
Mikael        text
```

So this is kinda a toggling to a regular text and select tag items.

So far I created use one stateful component and one stateless component or one stateful component. When state changed don't setState directly true it's opposite of current state isItClick : !this.state.isItClick

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ItemList from './ItemList';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    isItClick: false
  }
  this.clickfn = this.clickfn .bind(this);
}

clickfn = (value) => {
  this.setState(() => ({
    isItClick : !this.state.isItClick
  }));
}
render() {
   return (
      <div>
        {this.state.isItClick
          ? <ItemList clickfn ={this.clickfn }/>
          : <div className="myspace" onClick={this.clickfn }>TEXT</div>
        }

      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default App;
```

And then for my itemlist component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
const ItemList = (props) => {
return (
  <div className="my-space">
    <select onChange={(e) => props._handleClick(e.target.value)}>
      <option value="1">Item 1</option>
      <option value="2">Item 2</option>
      <option value="3">Item 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  );
}
export default ItemList;
```

Any idea what am I missing here? What do I need to fix to make it work based on my goals? Please help newbie here!

PS. Would appreciate a demo code.

Comment: This is a perfect time to try https://CodeSandbox.io to share your code.

Comment: Ok will create a sandbox

Comment: @Sean: here's the sandbox? https://codesandbox.io/s/43pr6q9pmx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have to set the clicked item id too in a state variable and in the render method of the list you will have to check the this id and return ItemList only for the clicked item. If you have posted the code to display the list I would have shared the edited code.
2. You will have to keep an array of states to keep track of each item in the list. In onChange of the select you will have to set the state value and App component's render should have the following statement

`<div className="myspace" onClick={this.clickfn }>{this.state.variableToTrackSelect}</div>`

I have posted the code posted in https://codesandbox.io/s/7y8k77nrm1.

Comment: Your example was for multiple items but the code was for a single item. Please post the actual code for more accurate reply.

Comment: Ok will create a sandbox

Comment: The sandbox looks incomplete. The ItemList.js is an empty file, there is no onclick event attached, the render function looks different from the above code. Please complete the sandbox code.

Comment: Let me know if you can see it.

Comment: It works except for the 1st item. If pull down the select item 1, the item1 remains a select tag. @Rohith Murali

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/7y8k77nrm1 check now. And please accept the answer for the stack over flow community

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170533/discussion-between-jon-dobie-and-rohith-murali).